# Generate a model into Ltspice where we can adjust a parameter

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to generate a subcircuit on ltspice. It is a first order filter where I would like to adjust the cuttoff frequency. I know that it is possible to do it on component but on a parameter ("param") I do not know how to do it.

[image]

I would like to set directly the param "fp" of the subcircuit. Does anyone know a way to do it ?

Have a nice day !

Comment: I'm confused. What you have there works exactly as you need: all you have to do is to use `fp` as the parameter to be passed to the subcircuit, and `Rfiltre` will be automatically calculated. It looks like you had no problem to start with, after all. :-)

Comment: Actually, my subject was not clear I wanted to do a netlist for a SUBCIRCUIT and I wanted to pass a parameter to this SUBCIRCUIT when I put it on my scheme. I found the solution :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about. Make the subcircuit out of what you have in the picture, then use `fp=<...>` as the parameter. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIcB0.png) are a thousand words. The green numbers indicate the order of the pins for the symbol I chose.

Comment: You re right ! Actually I did not write the parameter line on the same line of the SUBCKT. That was my error !

Comment: You can write them in two ways: on the same line with the `.subckt`, written as `params:` (note, no dot), or normally, as you have them. I forgot to add a `fp=100k` to the symbol, but I'm sure you already figured that out. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the tips ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it works in microcap): -

[image]

I didn't use the "=" (equate) to make these statements work but, they still work when you do use the equate (optional I guess). LTSpice might need the equate.

I think your main problem was expecting the raw "10n" to be recognized in the `.param Rfiltre` statement. Having said that, microcap will allow it. I can also keep the curly braces around `Rfiltre` in microcap too.

Comment: Thank youuuuuu !!!!